# Неверное расположение UniformGrid в ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Я пишу змейку и хочу сделать поле адаптивным.
Для этого я использую ItemsControl в котором у меня есть UniformGrid, которому через привязку передаю нужное количество столбцов и строчек.
У меня,во-первых не реагируют стили и не фасуются по гридам данные.

**XAML:**

```
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="White" >
            <ItemsControl  Background="#3A4047"  ItemsSource="{Binding FieldView}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="20" Height="20" Margin="1" Background="Black" >
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Snake">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Food">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding DataContext.Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                                Columns="{Binding DataContext.Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"></UniformGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

**Код:**

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>> Field { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Cell> FieldView { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Cell>();
   public int Width
        {
            get { return Field[0].Count; }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return Field.Count; }
        }
```

Field - двумерный массив. FieldView - преобразованный в одномерный.

**Хранимый объект:**

```
 public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Cell(CellState CState)
        {
            State = CState;
        }

        private CellState state;
        public CellState State
        {
            set
            {
                state = value;
                OnPropertyChenget();
            }

            get { return state; }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChenget([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Ваша логика со свойствами `Width` и `Height` (кстати на заметку `public int Height => Field.Count;`) не делает то, что вы ожидаете. Вы ожидаете то, что эти свойства мистическим образом будут прочитаны после каждого обновления коллекции, но запомните, UI не магия, он не лезет сам, пока его об этом не попросят, а попросить его можно либо через INPC, либо при рендере интерфейса. В вашем случае, у свойств нету сеттеров, а значит и оповещать об их изменении должен тот, кто меняется (коллекция). Подпишитесь на событие изменения и там вызывайте `OnPropertyChenget()` с именем свойства.

Comment: По коду: `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>` - коллекция `ObservableCollection` нужна тогда, когда надо оповестить интерфейс об изменениях коллекции, то есть данная коллекция реализует интерфейс, который скажет UI "ей, у меня новый объект, глянь!". Если вам не нужны эти оповещения, то и смысла использовать `ObservableCollection` нету. А судя по тому, что вы делаете змейку, у которой поле всегда статично и меняется максимум при создании, вам достаточно простого массива. `: INotifyPropertyChanged` - вынесите в отдельный класс и наследуйтесь от него там, где он нужен.

Comment: А как мне оповестить что допустим поле Field.Count изменилось ?

Comment: Я ведь сказал как, подпишитесь на событие изменения коллекции (оно одно) и вызывайте там метод `OnPropertyChenget()` для каждого свойства, с указанием его названия.

Comment: Аааа, понял, не знал такого, спасибо

Comment: добавил ```Field.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                OnPropertyChanget(nameof(Width));
                OnPropertyChanget(nameof(Height));
            };``` **Ничего не поменялось**

Comment: ```Field.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Height = Field.Count;
                Width = Field[0].Count;
               
            };``` **И так пробовал(добваил сетеры с INPC)**

Comment: Вы отладкой пройдитесь по коду и посмотрите, что и как там работает, получаются ли в этих свойствах те значения, которые вы ожидаете? Вот, к примеру у вас `Field` и `FieldView`, выше вы подписались на событие изменения для `Field`, но привязка идет к `FieldView`. Как это все и где заполняется, я лично не вижу. Может вы постоянно `=new()` делаете, а из-за того, что у коллекций вы не вызываете INPC, UI их не видит. Может вы не теми данными заполняете. Вариантов много. Попробуйте просто пройтись отладкой по коду, будет яснее для вас, что там не так.

Comment: Все вроде правильно, после инициализации все поля имеют те же значения что и должны. Я заметил вот какую деталь: если убрать Margin, то на экране вообще ничего не будет. В то время, когда с Margin посредине окна есть прямоугольник. FieldView убрал, так как, что с ним, что без него, ничего не меняется